# Do I have to grant public read access to my CloudFormation Templates for Nested Stacks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to use nested CloudFormation Stacks. In order to reference another template CloudFormation asks for an S3 URL. Does this have to be public? If I keep them private I get an access denied error while deploying...

This would be pretty strange if I would have to expose all my template to the open internet just so I can use nested stacks....